# How can I change web page requests coming from an application?

Tags: web-browsing, proxy, http

I'm using an app that makes http requests for content. I'd like to capture those requests and change them on the fly, so that a different request goes out to the http server, and thus different content comes back. I could do this with a full fledged web proxy, but I am hoping for a simpler and more transparent solution, possibly something that hooks into the OS to catch those network calls.

AdMuncher is my program of choice for this task on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [GlimmerBlocker](http://glimmerblocker.org) which primarily is an ad-blocking proxy but can also be used to rewrite requests and responses.

Comment: I'll try it. Configuring my system to use a proxy is not ideal, but if nothing better comes along then this one seems like it could be the best option.

Comment: AdMuncher works the same actually (from what I gather from the website), it's more or less the only way (unless you want to hack deeply into the relevant Cocoa libraries).

Comment: the difference is that AdMuncher hooks the network response functions in the OS, so you don't have to change configuration anywhere else. Any "normal" proxy software will involve telling the OS (or the browser itself) that you have a proxy that it should use. And some applications that open http connections at a lower level (such as `telnet google.com 80` from a console) would bypass such a proxy.